# PHP Excel 2007- cannot write to excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

Whenever I try to run this function and generate excel 2007 file, i get this error of no-response.
But, whenever I try to run this code for Excel5, the file generates. I have tried every other option, but this simply doesnt seem to work.

```
public function get_excel2(){
//load PHPExcel library
$this->load->library('Excel');

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("me")
                         ->setLastModifiedBy("myself")
                         ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                         ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                         ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated by PHP classes.")
                         ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                         ->setCategory("Test result file");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'bonjour')
        ->setCellValue('C2', 'monde')
        ->setCellValue('A4', 'testing');

// Rename worksheet (worksheet, not filename)
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('createdUsingPHPExcel');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as       the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
//clean the output buffer
ob_end_clean();

//this is the header given from PHPExcel examples. but the output seems somewhat corrupted in some cases.
//header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
//so, we use this header instead.
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="hogaboga.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at the logs so that you'll be able to tell us what doesn't seem to work actually means

Comment: Sending the correct content headers to match the filename/format that your'e sending to the browser might also help